# How to apply IE SSL MS Office document fix to entire web server?

Tags: iis-7, ssl, internet-explorer, microsoft-office

I've several areas on my web application where the user is allowed to download Microsoft Office documents.  I need to apply the fix listed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;316431)

> Web sites that want to allow this type of operation should remove the no-cache header or headers.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the CacheControlMode parameter [as described in IIS7 documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661%28WS.10%29.aspx) should do what you want:

> To set the expires response header to expire content periodically and
>   to set the number of seconds, minutes, hours, or days at which to
>   expire the content, use the following syntax:

```
appcmd set config /section:staticContent /clientCache.cacheControlMode:UseMaxAge /clientCache.cacheControlMaxAge: timeSpan
```

> The variable timeSpan is the time at which to expire the content. The
>   format for timeSpan is d.hh:mm:ss, where d is the optional number of
>   days, hh is the number of hours, mm is the number of minutes, and ss
>   is the number of seconds at which to expire the content. For example,
>   to set the cache to expire every two days, type the following and then
>   press ENTER:

```
appcmd set config /section:staticContent /clientCache.cacheControlMode:UseMaxAge /clientCache.cacheControlMaxAge:2.00:00:00
```

Comment: Actually, the opposite of that.

Comment: Oh, misread the question so I thought he wanted no-cache **set**. Thanks for noticing.